# implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.2.0'

Tags: service, google-play-services, android-service

when I use last version of `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.2.0'`, I receive an error message. In fact I have performed all the steps as they are in the documentation.

The error message is:

```
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5814)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5403)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5342)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

******************************************************************************
* Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here:                          *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to find your app ID.                                                       *
******************************************************************************


    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzyz.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.2.0:24)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.2.0:3)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5811)
        ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your admob application_id in project's manifest XML file like this:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="@string/your_ad_app_id" />
```

Comment: it does not work the same error + my application has stopped when running the emulator

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to get value for APPLICATION_ID from your Google Admob account and put it on AndroidManifest.xml as below correctly. Your account value starts with "ca-app-pub- *** "

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<manifest>
    <application
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy " />
    </application>
</manifest>
```